# NodeJS, HTTP Request doesn't Call a Callback Sometimes

Tags: node.js, events, https, callback, request

I'm developing a Request service under Nodejs. I'm using it in production for more than a year and it works fine, however, there are cases when it is stuck. It happens rarely on a particular kind of request, but I cannot isolate and fix the case.

It looks like there is a condition when the request doesn't call the `callback`. It looks like I'm missing some kind of erroneous event. I'm catching: `error`, `abort`, `timeout`, `end`...

What I'm missing?

```
function sendRequest(options, postData, callback) {

    const req = https.request(options, reqCallback);

    req.on('error', (err) => {
        callback(err.message, null);
    });

    req.on('abort', () => {
        callback('Request abort', null);
    });

    req.on('timeout', () => {
        callback('Request timeout', null);
    });

    if (postData) {
        req.write(postData);
    }

    req.end();

    function reqCallback(res) {
        const chunks = [];

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            let body = null;
            let err  = null;

            try {
                body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
            } catch (e) {
                err = e.message;
            }

            callback(err, body);
        });

        res.on('aborted', () => {
            callback('Response aborted', null);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the Request hangs up when the target server keeps the req open and doesn't respond.

I added a `Request-Timeout` header. It accepts time in seconds. However, the server may or may not execute a timeout.

I added a timeout directly to the request as follows.

```
function sendRequest(options, postData, callback) {
    const req = https.request(options, reqCallback)

    if (options.headers && typeof options.headers['Request-Timeout'] === 'number') {
        req.setTimeout(options.headers['Request-Timeout'] * 1000)
    }

    req.on('timeout', () => {
        // Destroy the request to prevent a double callback call.
        req.destroy()
    })
    
    // ...
}
```

I also added a specific `req.destroy()` in the body of the `timeout` event handler.
It prevents a subsequent callback call, if the server decides to respond at some moment.